# Read a table only once in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL query that uses a table more than once in the same query for which the UI shows the table is read for that many times (3). Is there any way to make Spark access the table just once ?

```
create temp view my_tab_v as
select prsn_id, cust_id, orig_dt, eff_dt
from db.my_tab_t
where state = 'MA';

with sub1 as
(
select prsn_id as indv, eff_dt
from my_tab_v
union
select cust_id as indv, eff_dt
from my_tab_v
),
sub2 as
(
select indv, eff_dt, row_number() over (partition by indv order by eff_dt desc) as rn
from sub1
)
select indv, '1900-01-01' as orig_dt, eff_dt
from sub2
where rn = 1
union
select prsn_id, orig_dt, eff_dt
from my_tab_v;
```

Spark UI `SQL tab` shows that the `db.my_tab_t` is being read `3` times. Is there any trick to make Spark read the table only once instead of 3 times ?

*Note: This is just an experimental query and mainly for educational purpose.*

I am using Spark SQL v 2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read the table into dataFrame, then call `df.cache()` if data fit in memmory or `df.persist()`. In this way, original table only be read once.

Comment: thanks for your reply, @Warren Zhu - I had thought of the `cache()` option but the table is very big to fit in the memory ~ 20GB..

Comment: Then you can use persist(), it can specify storage level such as disk.